# import postgres dump file to hdfs or hive table?

Tags: python, postgresql, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I have a dump file of a `postgreSQL` database with 10 GB as a size.

I know that we can use `Sqoop` to import `PostgreSQL` into `HDFS`, but I need to import this file to `hdfs` or hive as it is (dump file)?

Comment: More information about dump format needed

Comment: Why do you want to use `sqoop`, you can use `hdfs dfs -put <source> <dest-in-hdfs>`.

Comment: you want to put it as a file or as a table?

Comment: I want to put it as a table. It's format is .pgdump.

Comment: I want to have tables on hive as they are in postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There [is this existing github repository](https://github.com/spasam/pgdump-serde) allowing to load a postgres dump
directly into hive tables